# Как получить срез в python?

Tags: python

Нужно спарсить дату.
Получаю дату

```
for list in lists:
    try:
        time = list.find('div', class_='quote__header_date').text.strip()
    except:
        time = ''
    print(time)
```

Дата получается вот в таком формате

```
06.04.2021 в  9:12
```

Решил поделить ее по пробелам, чтобы убрать лишнее

```
def refine_time(s):
    return s.split(' ')
```

но не получается получить сразу первый и последний элемент

```
return s.split(' ')[0:-1]
```

так не работает

Comment: Нужна дата или дата со временем?

Comment: [Чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа, проголосуйте за ответ или отметьте его как решение.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 3):

```
a = '06.04.2021 в  9:12'
```

Есть разница в аргументах [.split()](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=split#str.split):

- без разделителя:

```
a.split()
['06.04.2021', 'в', '9:12']
```

- и ваш разделитель ' ' (пробел):

```
a.split(' ')
['06.04.2021', 'в', '', '9:12']
```

Но в любом случае, первый и последний - не [0:-1], а [0] и [-1]:

```
f'{a.split()[0]} {a.split()[-1]}'
'06.04.2021 9:12'
```

Comment: Можно срез с пропуском среднего элемента сделать, типа `a.split()[::2]`, потом сджойнить

Comment: @insolor да, но если `a = '06.04.2021 в то время, как космические корабли бороздят просторы Большого театра... 9:12'`? ;)

Comment: Ну когда будут бороздить, тогда уже думать)